# Oracle SQL - replace null with previous known value

Tags: sql, oracle, null

I am looking to replace null values from my table's column with the previous known value from that column. I have tried and searched many things but I can't seem to figure out how to do it. If someone could help that would be great. Thanks in advance!

```
PROCESSO    DATAM   HOURM TEMP_T1
-------- ---------- ----- -------
508410   2015.03.29  19   36.15
508410   2015.03.30  11   NULL
508410   2015.03.30  14   NULL
508410   2015.03.30  15   35.36
508410   2015.03.30  23   36.52
508410   2015.03.31  11   NULL
508410   2015.04.01  02   37.06
```

I want it to appear like this:

```
PROCESSO    DATAM   HOURM TEMP_T1
-------- ---------- ----- -------
508410   2015.03.29  19   36.15
508410   2015.03.30  11   36.15
508410   2015.03.30  14   36.15
508410   2015.03.30  15   35.36
508410   2015.03.30  23   36.52
508410   2015.03.31  11   36.52
508410   2015.04.01  02   37.06
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `last_value` analytic function:

```
SELECT "PROCESSO", "DATAM", "HOURM",
       last_value( "TEMP_T1" ignore nulls )
       OVER (order by "DATAM"
             rows between unbounded preceding and current row
       ) as new_temp
FROM table1
```

Demo ==> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/48207/2

**=========== EDIT ===================**
If you want to update the table, and there is no primary key (unique identifiers), you can try a solution based on rowid pseudocolumn 
==>http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns008.htm) :

```
MERGE INTO table1 t1
USING (
    SELECT rowid rd, "PROCESSO", "DATAM", "HOURM",
           last_value( "TEMP_T1" ignore nulls )
           OVER (order by "DATAM"
                 rows between unbounded preceding and current row
           ) as new_temp
    FROM table1
) x
ON (t1.rowid = x.rd)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET t1."TEMP_T1" = x.new_temp
;
```

Demo ==> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5a9a61/1

However you must ensure that there is no another process that deletes and inserts rows from/into this table while running the update, because when a row is deleted from the table, Oracle can assigng it's rowid to another, new row.

Comment: yes the select worked thank you @kordirko, though when i try to do the update it says: single-row subquery returns more than one row. I tried this: `update patient_vs_hourcolumn_table a set a.temp_t1=(
     SELECT 
       last_value( b.TEMP_T1 ignore nulls )
       OVER (order by b.processo, b.DATAM, b.hourm asc
             rows between unbounded preceding and current row
       ) as new_temp
FROM patient_vs_hourcolumn_table b)
where a.temp_t1 is null`

Comment: The windows (analytic) functions cannot be used directly in Update. Does this table have an unique identifier (primary key) ? It seems that the example in the question doesn't have any unique id - maybe i'am wrong, maybe `presso` + `hourm` together are unique within the table?. WIth unique id it's easy to use MERGE statement to update the table.

Comment: Ok, that's good to know, I think I will just export the select and then insert it, might do the trick! Thank you

Comment: There is no unique id in the table, the only possible way is by combining `processo`, `datam` and `hourm`

Comment: @Zalif please read the answer again, I've updated it and appended a solution based on rowid.